# Validation rule to make sure field in opportunity is filled in before the contract is activated

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to write a validation rule where i want to make sure that a field in opportunity called `Reason_for_not_getting_100_of_quote__c` is filled in if a amount field in contract is less than amount in opp.

Here is what i have done

```
IF( 
AND( 
Opportunity__r.Amount > Total_Contract_Value__c , 
LEN( Opportunity__r.Reason_for_not_getting_100_of_quote__c ) < 1,Text(Status) == "Activated"), True, False 
)
```

Total_Contract_Value__c = Rollup summary of line items

This is not firing. Any thoughts whats the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the IF, there is no need to return true or false with that, the VR will evaluate the AND itself. Also, use `ISBLANK` instead of checking for the LEN. That allows you to check for nulls, too.

```
AND( 
  Opportunity__r.Amount > Total_Contract_Value__c , 
  ISBLANK( Opportunity__r.Reason_for_not_getting_100_of_quote__c ),
  Text(Status) == "Activated"
)
```